# No one is clicking my slide box popup - Can it be improved?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, user-behavior, copywriting, popup

Earlier [I asked when it the right time](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/138391/best-practice-for-web-push-notifications-prompt/138397) to prompt the visitor to opt in for web push notifications (they work on both PC and Android devices).

I was just loading the default prompt and every day maybe just 5% or less than visitors have clicked "allow".

It was suggested I should wait for some user interaction, and show them some info for why they should opt in, so I decide to [use a slide box pop up](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Show-A-Popup-When-Scrolling-Down-slidebox.html) which shows right after user start to scroll down

I have attached my design.

I tested it for a whole day, and 0% have visitors have clicked "Activate Now".

What can I improve? Design, Copy, CTA?

I don't want to display the prompt only after a certain user action or time, since many users view the website just for information and that's fine. it doesn't mean they aren't interested, they just might not have the money to buy the item right now. So with notifications, I can send them an alert a week later for example. that's why it's important to collect permission from as many as possible, or I'll lost those leads for good.

[image: My SlideBox]

Comment: The obvious null hypothesis is that they don't want whatever it is you are trying to sell. No matter what they taught you in business school, no amount of usability engineering can bridge that gap.

Comment: I don't think that's the thing. some of them are clicking the links on the page. And if they visited the page in the first place, some of them are interested, not 100% of them but surely not 0% of them.

Comment: The reality is, most people don't want inboxes full of spam, and you can't change that. Any half-intelligent shopper will look for deals as and when they need to actually buy something. My point is, don't expect to get much interest from things like this.

Comment: You show this right after the user starts to scroll down?  So if I'm interested in your product, and I start reading to learn more about it, you immediately block me from reading what I'm trying to read, and ask me whether I'm interested in something else?  I'd say that's a question which I can't possibly answer at that time.  And if you're preventing me from reading about the thing that I'm actually trying to learn about, then sorry, but I'm leaving your site and never coming back.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem the timing is indeed a question. if I wait for too long, user might leave anyway and I won't have their subscription. some people will just look at the price and then leave. most people are already familiar with the product. right now it shows on the side, so it doesn't really block the view so much.

Comment: Users have been conditioned that pop-ups = "crap they are so uninterested in that the website has to force them to interact with it".

Comment: @tripleee: An even nuller hypothesis (to misuse the term a bit) is that most users don't even look at the content of the slide box (or popup &c) they just get rid of it.  Maybe if there's an obvious way to close it, they do, otherwise they just leave the page.

Comment: Yes, this popup can absolutely be improved. By ceasing to exist.

Comment: Another way to look at why people detest pop-ups is that they're "modal".  They wrest control from the user and force the user to deal with what the web-site designer wants instead of what the user came to do.  This breaks the user's train of thought by diverting them to a problem they have no interest in.   This is the IRL equivalent of the mail-person banging on your door and demanding you immediately read the adverts they just delivered.

Comment: @Jivan Lol'd after a long time.

Comment: No one wants an incredibly intrusive feature like this.

Answer (score 177):

Pop-up windows are a pestilence on the web.  Users are fed up with them.

People visited your web site because they wanted to view information about some product.  But as soon as they started scrolling down, an annoying pop-up window appeared in the middle of the screen, blocking what they were trying to read.

Their response was simple - get rid of that window by the quickest way possible, by clicking on the "X" button.  This allowed them to carry on with what they were reading.

> What can I improve? Design, Copy, CTA?

Get rid of it entirely.  Provide an option somewhere on the page that they can click on if they want to sign up for updates.  But be aware that most people wont click on a "please send me lots of spam on products that you want to sell to me" link.

Comment: I understand that you dislike popups, but that is not what the question is about.

Comment: @Nash My point is that improving the popup won't help.  You can make the text more informative, or the graphics prettier.  You can change the precise moment that it pops up.  None of this will help.  Users will close that popup as quickly as they can, regardless.  The only solution is to stop using annoying popup windows, and find another way to do it.

Comment: What if I use a sticky bar, like sticky on top, or on bottom? is there any research for what do users react better in those situations? most users won't just look for some link for updates, so I do want to make it more bold.

Comment: Your explanation might be too optimistic. The quickest way to get rid of unwanted popups on a site is to *close the main window, not the popup, and never visit that site again*.

Comment: OP asked literally "can [the popup] be improved?" and this answer explains why no one is clicking. The only improvement to this answer would be to start with with a large boldfaced "**No.** The popup cannot be improved in such a way as to make more people click on it." leading into the current first sentence "Pop-up windows are a pestilence..."

Comment: I'm new here, so maybe I've misunderstood the purpose of UX Stack Exchange. 

thenondeveloper asked for ways to improve their current method–they even listed out some areas that they're unsure on. Their clearly not experienced enough to see what was wrong with their approach; that's why they asked. 

Yes, they could remove the popup and do something less obtrusive (that's probably the best advice) but how does that answer help improve their abilities and the way they think about and approach UX in the future?

If something fails, so be it. We should at least help them try to get it right.

Comment: @ScottCameron This is called a "frame challenge", and is generally accepted in the Stack Exchange network: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263661/does-stack-exchange-allow-for-answers-which-question-the-validity-or-stance-of-t/263672#263672
In essence, sometimes the querent is expected to have more success with a different strategy; based on vote counts, this appears to be such a case.

Comment: It's an X/Y problem. OP has basically said '*I need Y to happen. I have tried X but it isn't working, so how can I fix X?*'. There's no point trying to fix 'X' if it's not actually going to solve 'Y'. It's like saying '*My car is out of fuel so I hit it on the wheel with a hammer but that didn't work, so where else should i hit it with the hammer?*'.

Comment: A cynical review the statement "Their response was simple - get rid of that window by the quickest way possible, by clicking on the "X" button." suggests that by hiding the x button and forcing the user to interact with the popup in a more meaningful manner would achieve what the user wants.

Comment: @Scott Cameron: "how does that answer help improve their abilities and the way they think about and approach UX in the future?" Obviously, if they read and accept this, they will stop using popups, sliders, and the like, which will vastly improve the user interfaces they create.  Duh!

Comment: @Sidney What was said is close the main window not click on the X button - ie close the site and probably never come back

Comment: @Sidney: If I, and I think the vast majority of users, can't immediately close the popup by clicking on the X or a close button, my response is almost always to leave the site.

Comment: @Nash the irony of your response is hilarious. Do you not see that that is exactly what your users are thinking about your popup?

Answer (score 39):

As other have said, most visitors have developed a [banner blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_blindness) and will either ignore or close your pop-up without reading its content. Improving the content of the banner will have minimal effect on this behavior.

**A better alternative would be to advertise your feature inside the page content and not as a generic overlay.** Depending on what value your feature provides, you should place an access to this feature in strategic locations:

- If your feature provides a way to track price change: **put a button next to the price labelled "Track"**. Here is an example of this that used to be implemented in Google Shopping*:
  [image]
- If your feature provides a way to subscribe to new offers without having to repeatedly make the same research: **put an action button on the search page labelled "Subscribe..."**. Here is an exemple of this implemented in the [Job Board Wordpress Plugin](https://wpjobboard.net/)*:[image]
- etc.

If all of the above is covered by the same feature (browser notifications), once a user click one of those buttons you can explain in a modal window the benefits of this feature (e.g. *"Activate notifications to get price tracking & much more..."*) with an action button to activate it.

Users will be much more attentive to the content of the modal that opened while looking for the feature than a pop-up that opened automatically out of context.

<sub>**: I have no affiliation with either of those websites, they're just the first results I found in Google image. Those screenshots are used for educational purpose only under the fair use policy. If anyone wants to replace them with wireframes, feel free to do so.*</sub>

Comment: This is the difference between *asking* the user to use a feature and simply making it available should the user wish to use it. The former is viewed as the annoying digital equivalent to a telemarketer. The latter is much better UX because the user is in control at all times.

Answer (score 25):

There are a few issues that spring to mind here.

**For example:**

- The title of your Popup is 'New Feature!', but you don't explain clearly what that feature is OR **why it's of value to the user**.
- If the current 'deal' the user is viewing isn't interesting, **why would they want updates of a similar type**?
- The button text says 'Activate Now'. Again, the user may not fully understand **what you are asking them to activate** OR how this 'feature' benefits them.

Employ some meaningful UX copywriting to grab the attention of the user. The title could read something like: *'Get notified about new deals!'* or *'Find out when new deals launch!'*. This will introduce the benefit before the ask for a commitment.

Make the body copy more informative; tell the user what benefit they can expect to receive for choosing to activate notifications and why it's a great idea. Generalize this so it doesn't sound specific to whatever they're currently viewing.

Lastly, change the button copy to something more **human**: *'Yes, please'* or *'Sure, notify me'*. Adding a secondary CTA to allow users to say *'No, thanks'* could be beneficial for tracking your Yes vs No % rate over time.

Comment: Nice suggestions. to answer "why 'deal' the user is viewing isn't interesting", it's a bit tricky - some users would buy if the price was lower. but I don't want to explicitly tell them to subscribe and wait for a better price alert, because then other users might not buy at the existing price, after seeing such message, and they will think I admit that if they wait they might get a better price. any way how to take on that?

Comment: I doubt that the users are even reading the popup before they click the X. They just see an annoying interfering popup over the text they were trying to read and, as Simon B says, they click the X as fast as they can so they can get back to the task at hand as soon as possible.

Comment: @thenondeveloper Please internalize shoover's comment. People really don't read popups and decide whether they want to engage with the CTA. They look for the x to close the popup, or they just leave the site.

Answer (score 18):

#### TL;DR You don't, and can't, get high response rates because nobody wants the notifications.

Nobody, and I mean **NOBODY**, actually **wants** to "opt in for web push notifications".

That is the core problem.

One of the absolute top things I do on a customer's computer the first time I work on it is to remove existing browser push notifications and turn off the ability of web sites to ask to add new notifications (the action that presumably is attempted if someone clicks "Activate Now"). I have **never** had anyone say "oh, I want to keep those notifications. Never. The vast majority of the time they don't even say anything because they don't realize how easy it is (in Firefox, Chrome and many other browsers) to stop the notifications. Until I say "should I get rid of these notifications" and they typically tell me "Yes, please!"

Nobody wants these things. **NOBODY.**

Email is a different story. There are many people who are OK with periodic (weekly or even daily) emails from many different vendors or other organizations. There is a big difference between email and web push notifications: **Control.** The end user can delete the email as easily as they can close the push notification. But they also only see those emails when they **want** to look at email. If they are doing something else, they don't get bothered with notifications. In addition, power users can setup filters to automatically file the emails so that they are even less intrusive.

Comment: I don't agree that the feature is entirely unwanted. I have occasionally deliberately signed up to get notified when a particular live stream starts. I also believe there some people want notifications from web apps like gmail.

It's just that nobody wants them used as advertisements instead of being actual notifications.

Comment: I would take those same notifications (as I do with appointment reminders, Google Doc updates, etc.) via email. Not *guaranteed* timing, but by and large unless your internet connection is down (in which case a live stream isn't going to work either) pretty fast and "good enough" - and still retain control over when/where I see the notifications, etc.

Comment: That's if you're not relying on a web email client which can only notify you via this very mechanism.

Comment: The people I know relying on a web email client (even myself if I am at a customer site, under some limited circumstances) just pop over to that browser tab every so often. Plus if you're using a borrowed computer (friend/family, library, etc.) then you often couldn't (or at least shouldn't) turn on notifications anyway.

Comment: I think the only cases most users actually want to click a "notify me" button is when it's for something very very specific. Typically a "let me know when this product is available" situation. Or alternately, when they're job-hunting or similar and need to be notified of jobs meeting their criteria. "Give us your email so we can send you stuff we think you might be interested in" might as well read "We want to spam you, click here to let us" as far as most users are concerned. Likewise with push-notifications or allowing the site to know your location. It's just not in the client's interest.

Answer (score 14):

I think the biggest issue here is that it's not clear what will happen once I click that CTA (as Scott mentioned).

Where and how will I be notified? "Activate" sounds like I will be installing a new program or browser extension.
The best thing to do is just make it more clear what you actually mean.

---

Another issue could be, that it visually looks like an ad and people have developed a [banner blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_blindness).
Though I am not a visual designer and don't know what exactly would have to be improved in that regard.

Maybe the icon could already show more?

Comment: every time user views page, the price he see might be different. so I developed push alert system with the idea of sending alerts when the price drops, if user did not buy the item. however, I don't want to explicitly use a text that will tell the user "the price you see now might be lower later. if you don't want to buy the item now, you can subscribe to get push alerts to your browser, and we will send you an alert if and when the price drops". This will hinder the conversion from users who would have bought at the current price.

Comment: @thenondeveloper I understand, but I'm not saying explain in 100% detail what will happen etc. Just a bit more context to what "activate now" will do. For example something like "Not sure yet? Set up notifications when this or similar products go on sale!".

Comment: @thenondeveloper Look eg at idealo.co.uk - they have price history and price alert sections, absolutely nonintrusive, even I _almost_ clicked on price alert few times :)

Comment: @Arvo I think displaying price history is actually a very bad idea from a business perspective. it's like telling the customer, don't buy now, there was a lower price just a week ago, so why not wait few weeks until that price might (or might not) come back.

Comment: @thenondeveloper would you yourself sign up for push notifications on vague promise about "similar deals"? Have you ever agreed to something like that?

Comment: @thenondeveloper This site was just an example of good ux, they do not sell anything themselves, they just aggregate price info - thereby no bad business there :)

Comment: @thenondeveloper If it's bad for your business for people to know what your historical prices are, why do you change your prices like that? You're in the business of selling things that people want for a fair price, not deceiving people into buying things for an unfair price. (Aren't you?)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 prices fluctuate based on demand and supply, it's not something I can control myself. that's just my market. it has nothing to do with deceiving.

Comment: @thenondeveloper Hmm. In which case, wouldn't it be strictly better for you to make the market more efficient? Having people checking back for a better price later _can't_ be bad; it's more people checking your site more often while considering a purchase.

Answer (score 11):

Drop the popup, make it an option in the main page.  And make it look better integrated with the rest of the page (e.g include it in a list of options with "buy now" and "add to wishlist")

At the moment, that look like an advert, spam, or clickbait, trying to *trick* users into going to a different (potentially malicious) website.  It hits almost every red flag and alarm bell in my head, bar two: it's not trying to say that I've won anything, and it's not showing or implying people in various states of undress.

If you **insist** on having a popup of sorts, then there are 3 ways to make it look less like a phishing expedition, and more like it actually belongs on the website.  First, try to improve the text slightly.  "Activate Now" does not make sense in that context, try something like "Add Alert" (and, include a "manage alerts" button beneath it, so that people can check what types of products/deals they are currently subscribed to), and probably get rid of the "New Feature!" title.

The other two options would be to have it as a narrow bar along the bottom of the screen, or to have it appear in what would normally be whitespace (e.g. the StackOverflow "Manage Cookies" popup, which appears under the menu on the left of the screen) — notably, both of these ensure that you don't block the user's attempt to view the actual content.

Answer (score 9):

It's possible that 95% of your visitors don't want push notifications.

My humble suggestion: Put two more buttons on the pop-up.  One that says, "Close this popup" and a second that says, "Close this popup and never show me another pop-up on this site again."

Tally your responses.  That will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I can answer this question. Couple of years back I faced similar issue of users not clicking the pop-up as I desired. So, as you have mentioned that users would mostly leave the page after they get the desired information. In order to increase the conversion rate what I did was, instead of using the pop-ups I used to place the same content of pop-up box into a placeholder so subtly that it would blend-in with the rest of the content and at the same time it wouldn't stand-out as a pop-up, still would hold it's relevance and convey the desired message.

For e.g., Let's say the article was on optimising the memory(space complexity) of a search algorithm. So I would place one or two subtle placeholders saying 'Get weekly article on optimising algorithms in your email' and similar with the CTA containing similar accent colour. And at the end of the article I'd place another message placeholder saying:
'Get more algorithm optimisation guides delivered directly into your inbox! **Send me the weekly news letter**'

I hope it gives you some kind of rough idea to begin with.